# How to measure time intervals in flash excluding periods when it's paused by a browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to measure time of an event in a game. Currently I simply save timestamps when an event starts and when it finishes, and calculate the difference.

The problem comes when a user switches tabs in a browser during an event. This causes flash to be paused, which messes up my interval calculation as it depends on "real" time, not time when flash is "alive".

Is there any simple solution to this? Like some internal timer that gets paused with the rest of the game which I can initiate and check instead of subtracting timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

If you can detect when the user switches tabs (maybe a blur event) in javascript, you could use localconnection to tell flash to save another timestamp, then when the page regains focus, send flash another timestamp.  Instead of subtracting just two timestamps, now you'll have to toggle back and forth between adding the difference and ignoring it.

Answer (score 0):

First, start a regular Timer().  Then add listeners for activate and deactivate... these events fire when your app loses focus (user goes to another tab, another app, etc):

```
addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, activateListener);
addEventListener(Event.DEACTIVATE, deactivateListener);
```

Then stop and start your timer in the listener methods.

Comment: How can I measure intervals with the timer though? I don't see a way to get number of ms since it started.

Comment: var start = flash.utils.getTimer(); var end = flash.utils.getTimer() - start;

Comment: Tried catching `Event.DEACTIVATE` but for some reason it works only in local swf preview, when embedded into html page it is not triggered (tried in Chrome and FF).

Comment: I just tested in chrome and it worked for me.  Are you sure you are listening in the main application scope? As in myApp.addEventListener...